# Streaming data between akka cluster nodes

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, loops, akka-cluster

I need to stream data between a couple hundred KB and many MBs between akka cluster nodes. Simplest approach would be to split it up as chunked messages, but that appears to be in advisable because it might interfere with housekeeping chatter of the cluster.

Alternatively, I could use messages to communicate one time urls and use http.

However, I'd prefer a persistent connection approach, so I was thinking using zeromq and chunked messages.

But rather than rolling my own approach, I'd like to use an existing way of accomplishing this but I have not found one.

One more requirement: most of the time the consumption of that stream is going straight out via Play, so an approach that created an iteratee that could be used to proxy the steam to http would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka Streams 2.5.12 has [StreamRefs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-refs.html) for what I believe to be your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Iteratees can't communicate across machine boundaries, so iteratees alone are probably not the tool you are looking for.

I would pursue one of the following approaches:

1. Using remote rpc akka Actors to send chunks of your data across the wire. Actors can be used to create iteratees and enumerators on either side (`Enumerator.unicast` and `Iteratee.foreach`) of the wire so that the fact that you are using Actors is just an implementation detail and not visible in your interface of these streams.
2. Use [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala.html?_ga=1.62274725.843267270.1438725976). This library has support for TCP connections, and while this is a different streaming library from iteratees, I have found that it is more robust in the stream operations it supports. It looks like Play is looking to move [towards a tighter integration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/AkkaHttpServer) with Akka Streams as they are looking at replacing their netty HTTP backend with Akka Http Streams